# What's wrong with my program? I want the coordinate values to be saved but it keeps resetting to 0,0 after every loop

Tags: c++, save

What's wrong with my program? I want the coordinate values to be saved but it keeps resetting to 0,0 after every loop.if you run my main file with the .h in the same folder, you'll see that the coord values reset after the loop finishes. very frustrating.

my .h file
the not- saving part is most likely in the move() function
thanks so much :)
i've tried everything, is there something i'm doing wrong?

```
using namespace std;
    #include <string>
    #define FORWARD 0
    #define BACKWARD -1
    #define RIGHT 2
    #define LEFT -2
    #define t true
    class Player
    {
        public:
        //x pos
        float x;
        //y pos
        float y;
        //id of player
        string id;
    };
    string d;
    string mv;
    // Making a new player
    Player p;

    int direction;


    void turnForward()
    {
        direction = FORWARD;
    }

    void turnBackward()
    {
       direction = BACKWARD;
    }

    void turnRight()
    {
        direction = RIGHT;
    }

    void turnLeft()
    {
        direction = LEFT;
    }

    int spaces;

    void move(int spaces, int direction, float x, float y, Player p)
    {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        if(direction == LEFT)
        {
            x = x - spaces;

            cout << x << ","<<   y << endl;
        }
          p.x = x;

        if(direction == RIGHT)
        {
            x = x + spaces;

            cout << x << ","<<   y << endl;
        }
        p.x = x;

        if(direction == FORWARD)
        {
            y = y + spaces;

            cout << x << ","<<   y << endl;
        }
        p.y = y;
        if(direction == BACKWARD)
        {
            y = y - spaces;

            cout << x << ","<<    y << endl;
        }
         p.y = y;

    }
```

my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#import <string>
#include "assets.h"
using namespace std;

void run()
{

        while(t)
    {
    cout << "What direction would you like to turn? Left (L), Right (R), Forward (F), Backward (B) ";
        cin >> d;
        if(d == "L" || d == "l")
        {
            turnLeft();
            cout << "Would you like to move " << d << "? Y/N ";
            cin >> mv;
            if(mv == "Y" || mv == "y")
            {
                cout << "How many spaces would you like to go " <<d << "? ";
                cin >> spaces;
                move(spaces, direction, p.x, p.y, p);
            }
            else
            {
                run();
            }
        }
        if(d == "R" || d == "r")
        {
            turnRight();
            cout << "Would you like to move " << d << "? Y/N ";
            cin >> mv;
            if(mv == "Y" || mv == "y")
            {
                cout << "How many spaces would you like to go " <<d << "? ";
                cin >> spaces;
                move(spaces, direction, p.x, p.y, p);
            }
            else
            {
                run();
            }
        }

        if(d == "F" || d == "f")
        {
            turnForward();
            cout << "Would you like to move " << d << "? Y/N ";
            cin >> mv;
            if(mv == "Y" || mv == "y")
            {
                cout << "How many spaces would you like to go " <<d << "? ";
                cin >> spaces;
                move(spaces, direction, p.x, p.y, p);
            }
            else
            {
                run();
            }
        }

        if(d == "B" || d == "b")
        {
                turnBackward();
                cout << "Would you like to move " << d << "? Y/N ";
                cin >> mv;
                if(mv == "Y" || mv == "y")
                {
                    cout << "How many spaces would you like to go " <<d << "? ";
                    cin >> spaces;
                    move(spaces, direction, p.x, p.y, p);
                }
                else
                {
                    run();  
                }
            }

    }

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
        cout << "Enter in your name (This will be your username): ";
        cin >> p.id;

        run();

}
```

main file calls `run()`

Comment: Why do you have function definitions in your `.h` file? Functions should be in `.cpp`. Header files should contain only macros and declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `p` by value, not by reference. So `move()` is modifying a copy of the player. Change `move()` to:

```
void move(int spaces, int direction, float x, float y, Player &p)
```

Comment: The first two lines of `move()` are immediately discarding the passed values for what's in the class, so that also needs to be resolved.

Comment: @Olipro He always calls it as `move(spaces, direction, p.x, p.y, p);`. Then `move()` does `x = p.x; y=p.y`. So he's setting the parameters to what they were set to before. He obviously doesn't need to pass those parameters in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In your move() method you are resetting parameter value of x and y to p.x and p.y. Where you have initialized values for p? 
Every time loop executed it is passing the copy of object Person so if you change any value for that object inside the move() method it will not get effected in run() method. As Barmar mentioned you have to pass value by reference or return updated Person object from move() method and assign it back to object p in run() method.